# Python Update a submatrix given the indexes by a 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Simple enough implementation with a for loop. Example:

```
s = np.zeros((3,3))
b = np.array(([0,1],[0,1],[2,0]))
for line in range(s.shape[0]):
    s[line][b[line]] = 1
```

What i would like to do is to update the matrix without the for loop. Something like

```
s[b] = 1
```

But the s[b].shape returns a (3,2,3) matrix.
Is there any way to fix that or i have to make a for loop for every line?

Comment: That `s[line][b[line]]` indexing is really weird for a 2D `s` and 3D `b`. Can you explain what you were trying to do there and why? (I can see what it would do, but what it would do is weird enough that I suspect you may have gotten it wrong.)

Comment: every line in b contains the indexes that must be updated for the corresponding line in the matrix S.  I can't see a manner for doing that without the  s[line][b[line]].

Comment: Okay, so you did get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s[np.arange(s.shape[0])[..., None], b] = 1
```

We use some tricky advanced indexing here. The `np.arange(s.shape[0])[..., None]` produces the column vector

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

which broadcasts against `b` to select, for each row of `s`, the column indices given by the elements of that row of `b`.

Comment: Perfect, that works fine! Do you know if that gives a speed-up? Or is just the same with the for loop but more "beautiful"?

Comment: @CfisYoi: I would expect it to provide at least some speed-up, but I've seen surprisingly slow results from multidimensional advanced indexing at times. I'd recommend timing it.